# Find absolute max value in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, max, absolute

I am looking for a nice way to find the maximum ABSOLUTE value of an array.

My array is i.e.

```
var array = [10,20,40,-30,-20,50,-60];
```

Then:

```
Math.max.apply(null,array);
```

Will result in '50'. But, actually, I want it to return '60'.

The option is to create a second array using Math.abs, but actually I am wondering if the apply function can be combined, so it is one elegant solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Math.max.apply(null, array.map(Math.abs));
```

If you target browsers that don't support Array.prototype.map (IE<=8), use [the polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) or a library like [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/map).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var array = [10,20,40,-30,-20,50,-60];
var absMax = array.reduce(function(max, item){
    return Math.max(Math.abs(max),Math.abs(item));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the above answer is a bit more elegant, but yours had gave me some nice 'aha'. Still lot to learn about JS.

Answer (score 3):

**How this**

```
var array = [10,20,40,-30,-20,50,-60];    
return Math.max(...array.map(a => Math.abs(a)))
```

Comment: Definitely the best way in 2020 :)